# Kong unable handle image response from upstream

Tags: nginx, api-gateway, kong

imagine that i have kong running on "server a", and "server b" are the upstream golang rest application.

When I access via ip server b direct directly, I can get image response,
but when I access through the kong domain, which handled by nginx from kong itself, I get standard response 404 not found nginx ? Why?

Meanwhile if I access a route that has response rest json via kong it works normally.